# Find a nearest/closest point on a GameObject from location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I want to find out a point on boom section from load hanging on crane which have minimum distance from load, crane-Boom having `BoxCollider` on hit and I am using `Physics.overlap` method.

How do you find a closest point on a GameObject from source object?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBRqm.png[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can we some pictures?

Comment: May be image can help to understand my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that with [`Collider.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html) and [`Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html). If you also want to check for custom position and rotation instead of using the collider's postion and roation then use [`Physics.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ClosestPoint.html).

Example usage for 3 of these functions:

```
public Vector3 sourceObject;
public Collider targetCollider;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Method 1
    Vector3 closestPoint = targetCollider.ClosestPoint(sourceObject);

    //Method 2
    Vector3 closestPointInBounds = targetCollider.ClosestPointOnBounds(sourceObject);

    //Method 3
    Vector3 pos = targetCollider.transform.position;
    Quaternion rot = targetCollider.transform.rotation;
    Vector3 closestPointCollider = Physics.ClosestPoint(sourceObject, targetCollider, pos, rot);
}
```

Comment: closestPointCollider return a point outside the crane Boom part which is above the crane.